# The "lives" in my game won't appear? pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

So, in my memory game, I got that when you click a wrong button, you lose a life. And this works! After losing 3 lives, you lose. But the problem here is that the text for the lives won't appear in my game once it starts up. Could anyone help me out? (If you're interested in seeing the entire code, then you could look at it here http://pastebin.com/rkBGC2rD)

```
def main():
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF, BASICFONT, BEEP1, BEEP2, BEEP3, BEEP4

    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Simulate')

    # font 
    BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)

    # load the sound files
    BEEP1 = pygame.mixer.Sound('beep1.wav')
    BEEP2 = pygame.mixer.Sound('beep2.wav')
    BEEP3 = pygame.mixer.Sound('beep3.wav')
    BEEP4 = pygame.mixer.Sound('beep4.wav')
    SOUNDTRACK = pygame.mixer.Sound('soundtrack.wav')
    ERROR = pygame.mixer.Sound('error.wav')

    # initialize some variables for a new game
    pattern = [] # stores the pattern of colors
    currentStep = 0 # the color the player must push next
    lastClickTime = 0 # "time stamp" of the player's last button push
    score = 0

    # plays the soundtrack music 
    SOUNDTRACK.play(-1, 0, 1000)

    # start-up screen text
    text = BASICFONT.render('Press enter to play!', 1, WHITE)
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.centerx = DISPLAYSURF.get_rect().centerx
    textRect.y = 150
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(text, textRect)

    # update the screen
    pygame.display.update()

    # the start up screen command
    waiting = True
    while waiting:      
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    waiting = False

    # amount of lives
    lives = 3
    img = BASICFONT.render('I'*lives, 1, WHITE)
    livesRect = img.get_rect()
    livesRect.topleft = (10, 10)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(img, livesRect)

    # when False, the pattern is playing. when True, waiting for the player to click a colored button:
    waitingForInput = False

    while True: # main game loop
        clickedButton = None # button that was clicked (set to YELLOW, RED, GREEN, or BLUE)
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(bgColor)
        drawButtons()

        scoreSurf = BASICFONT.render('Score: ' + str(score), 1, WHITE)
        scoreRect = scoreSurf.get_rect()
        scoreRect.topleft = (WIDTH - 100, 10)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(scoreSurf, scoreRect)      

        checkForQuit()
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # event handling loop
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mousex, mousey = event.pos
                clickedButton = getButtonClicked(mousex, mousey)

        if not waitingForInput:
            # play the pattern
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.wait(1000)
            pattern.append(random.choice((YELLOW, BLUE, RED, GREEN)))
            for button in pattern:
                flashButtonAnimation(button)
                pygame.time.wait(FLASHDELAY)
            waitingForInput = True
        else:
            # wait for the player to enter buttons
            if clickedButton and clickedButton == pattern[currentStep]:
                # pushed the correct button
                flashButtonAnimation(clickedButton)
                currentStep += 1
                lastClickTime = time.time()

                if currentStep == len(pattern):
                    # pushed the last button in the pattern
                    score += 1
                    waitingForInput = False
                    currentStep = 0 # reset back to first step

            elif (clickedButton and clickedButton != pattern[currentStep]) or (currentStep != 0 and time.time() - TIMEOUT > lastClickTime):
                # pushed the incorrect button, or has timed out
                pattern = []
                currentStep = 0
                waitingForInput = False
                lives = lives - 1
                SOUNDTRACK.stop()
                ERROR.play()
                pygame.time.wait(1000)
                SOUNDTRACK.play(-1, 0, 1000)
                pygame.display.update()
                if lives < 1:               
                    gameOverAnimation()
                    # reset the variables for a new game:
                    pattern = []
                    currentStep = 0
                    waitingForInput = False
                    score = 0
                    pygame.time.wait(1000)

        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Put some code from mainloop into functions to make it cleaner. Create classes. Read [Making Games with Python & Pygame](http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapters/). By the way: you can use `pygame.time.get_ticks()` in place of `time.time()`.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you change `lives` you have to render again

```
img = BASICFONT.render('I'*lives, 1, WHITE)
```

and display it in every loop

```
DISPLAYSURF.blit(img, livesRect)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the main loop, you fill over the entire background with `DISPLAYSURF.fill(bgColor)` but don't draw `livesRect` again.

Comment: Okay, so I did that and it worked! But now the number of lives doesn't decrease? @Philip

Comment: are you re-rendering `livesRect` each time with the updated number of lives or just using the same one over and over again?